# In this function what does the first parameter (e) do?

Tags: reactjs

In this react function what does the first parameter do?

`const handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name);`

Comment: debug `console.log(e)` Look where `handleItemClick` is called

Answer (score 0):

First parameters e detects which type of event occurs when you perform any action by using this type of function.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently whatever calls that handler calls it with an event object as the first argument and an object as the second argument, and the handler's code doesn't need to use the event object for anything (and only needs the `name` property from the object). So the sole purpose of `e` there is to consume the first argument so the `{ name }` can consume the `name` property from the second.

E.g., analogous to this:

```js
const handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => console.log(name);

handleItemClick(
    new MouseEvent("click"), // First argument, not used by the handler
    {name: "Joe"}            // Second argument, Used by the handler
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`e` contains whole mouse events. Using this you can identify which Key was pressed and what is the ASCII KeyCode of it and many more.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter is the event object of some derived type of the `SyntheticEvent`. This means that the function is used as an event handler. You can use this object to get information about the event like its type, the elements related to it, etc...